# How to ensure that a transaction is successful?

Tags: web3.js, send-transaction, sendandconfirmrawtransaction

I am sending transactions using the Solana web3js library:

1. `sendRawTransaction`
2. `confirmTransaction` w/ "confirmed" commitment.

Although, how would I check that the tx was actually successful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I had to do was check for the return value of the confirmTransaction

```
const result = await connection.confirmTransaction(...);
if (result.value.err) { /* log err due to failed tx */}
```

[Thanks Josip!](https://twitter.com/JosipVolarevic2)

[And others on this Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/burger606/status/1662583419090468864?s=20)

Answer (score 0):

you can check the transaction status
like this

First, get the transactionId

> let txid = await sendRawTransaction(transaction, connection);

Then go to this URL in Solana Explorer and check the status(pending and confirmed)

> console.log(`Transaction submitted: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txid}?cluster=devnet`);

Specify the cluster in URL as you want devnet Mainnet etc.